# EasyPhp Foreign Key

Tags: php, sql, database, easyphp

I have a problem with EasyPHP. I have a web page un php, with a database creation script, which i think is right, but i do not understand why the "on delete cascade" doesn't work.

Here is my script :

```
//Création de la table Enquete
$tabenq = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 1_Enquete (
idEnquete INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
nomEnquete VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (idEnquete));";
//Création de la table rubrique
$tabrub = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 2_Rubrique (
idRubrique INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
nomRubrique VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
idEnquete INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (idRubrique),
INDEX idEnq_ind (idEnquete),
FOREIGN KEY (idEnquete) REFERENCES 1_Enquete(idEnquete) ON DELETE CASCADE);";
//Création de la table Q1
$tabq1 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 3_Q1 (
idQ1 INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
libelleQ1 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
idRubrique INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (idQ1),
INDEX idRub_ind (idRubrique),
FOREIGN KEY (idRubrique) REFERENCES 2_Rubrique(idRubrique) ON DELETE CASCADE);";
//Création de la table Q2
$tabq2 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 4_Q2 (
idQ2 INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
libelleQ2 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
idQ1 INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (idQ2),
INDEX idQ1_ind (idQ1),
FOREIGN KEY (idQ1) REFERENCES 3_Q1(idQ1) ON DELETE CASCADE)";
//Création de la table Campagne
$tabCamp = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 5_Campagne (
idCampagne INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
dateCampagne DATE NOT NULL,
idEnquete INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (idCampagne),
INDEX idEnqCamp_ind (idEnquete),
FOREIGN KEY (idEnquete) REFERENCES 1_Enquete(idEnquete) ON DELETE CASCADE);";
```

[DB architecture in EasyPHP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74rcg.png)

There is no link between tables, and i don't understand why... does anyone have a clue?

Comment: specifies that the child data is deleted when the parent data is deleted.

Comment: Also It is used in conjunction with ON DELETE or ON UPDATE. It means that the child data is either deleted or updated when the parent data is deleted or updated.

Comment: i have already done this in my creation script :  CREATE TABLE .... ON DELETE CASCADE 

But thanks for your help, i found something. It's working if i add :

    ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

in each creation script like : 
CREATE TABLE... (...)  ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;";